# Should I use 'are' or 'is' in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct?

> Our first choice are garden Mum’s.
>
> Our first choice is garden Mum’s.

Comment: The flowers are *mums* (short for *chrysanthemums*), not *Mum's*, which is the genitive of the epithet/noun of address *Mum* = our mother.

Comment: Hello StoneyB, I appreciate the correction on Mums.

Comment: Patricia, as StoneyB wrote correctly, there's no need to capitalize mums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Choice' is singular. You should use 'is'.